# PHP PDO how do i include fetch assoc and numrows

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

trying to convert all my old `mysql_*` operations into new and, from what i've heard, improved PDO, but this query wont seem to run successfully, I am trying to select all from the table PEOPLE where the username = $username (which has previously been declared `$username = $_SESSION['username'];`)

```
$query = "SELECT  * FROM people WHERE username=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $username);   
$stmt->execute();
$num_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if ($num_rows == 1) {
    // ...
}
```

THE WORKING CODE IS:

```
$query = "SELECT  * FROM people 
             WHERE username=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(1, $username);   
$stmt->execute();
$num_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$user = $stmt->fetchObject();

if ($user) {

//do something

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest, in this case, LIMIT 1 at the end of your query.  You know you will either have 1 or 0 users with any given username, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$stmt->fetchColumn` does not fetch the number of rows; in this case it will fetch the first column from the first row of the result set. Since that will not be equal to `1` generally your test will fail.

In this case there is also no real need to count the number of returned rows because you are expecting either one or zero (if the username does not exist). So you can simply do:

```
$stmt->execute();
$user = $stmt->fetchObject();
if (!$user) {
    // not found
}
else {
    echo "User $user->username found!";
}
```

The `if(!$user)` test works because if there is no row to fetch `$user` will be `false` (see the documentation for [`fetchObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchobject.php)).

Comment: thanks for your reply, okay so how would i go about fetching the number of rows

Comment: @neeko: See the updated answer. Almost all of the time there is no need to get the number of rows, just iterate over them. If you need to count something it's far better to use `SELECT COUNT(...)` instead.

Comment: thank you!! this is now working!! slowly i am trying to change my old operations, I was wondering if you knew what kind of benefits performing a query using PDO would have over using the old mysql_*?

Comment: @neeko: Several benefits. Protection against SQL injection attacks first and foremost.

Comment: thankyou, also, how would you rate the security of the working statement in the question?

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM people WHERE username = :username";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);   
$stmt->execute();

while ($row = $stmt->fetchObject()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) as the num_rows and [PDOStatement::fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) as fetch_assoc equivalent.

Comment: everybody missed fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
```

instead.